# Can Liquibase use DB2's multiple tablespaces?

Tags: db2, liquibase, db2-luw

In DB2 LUW it is [recommended](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22526/db2-is-it-good-to-create-the-index-table-space-to-use-32-kb-data-page) that tables, indexes and "long objects" (ie LOBs) should be placed in separate tablespaces. Our existing SQL scripts have lines like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "APPLICATIONTABLE"(
    APPLICATIONID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    APPLICATIONNAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)IN USERSPACE1 INDEX IN USERSPACE2 LONG IN USERSPACE3;
```

In a changeset we can specifiy a tablespace:

```xml
<createTable tableName="APPLICATIONTABLE" tablespace="${tablespace.data}">
    <column name="APPLICATIONID" type="NUMBER(4, 0)">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="APPLICATIONNAME" type="VARCHAR(30)">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
</createTable>
```

But not, as far as I can see, DB2's multiple tablespaces. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`sql` change](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) which liquibase doc describes as:

> The ‘sql’ tag allows you to specify whatever sql you want. It is useful for complex changes that aren’t supported through Liquibase’s automated refactoring tags and to work around bugs and limitations of Liquibase. The SQL contained in the sql tag can be multi-line.

It looks like this (copied from the liquibase doc):

```xml
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="sql-example">
    <sql dbms="h2, oracle"
            endDelimiter="\nGO"
            splitStatements="true"
            stripComments="true">insert into person (name) values ('Bob')
        <comment>What about Bob?</comment>
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

**EDIT:**

Just saw another option after reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28241099/332248). 
You could use the [`modifySql`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/modify_sql.html) tag. Maybe leave out tablespace info and just append it like this (untested code - just a suggestion):

```xml
<createTable tableName="APPLICATIONTABLE">
    <column name="APPLICATIONID" type="NUMBER(4, 0)">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="APPLICATIONNAME" type="VARCHAR(30)">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <modifySql dbms="db2">
        <append value=" IN USERSPACE1 INDEX IN USERSPACE2 LONG IN USERSPACE3"/>
    </modifySql>
</createTable>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that crossed my mind. But as in our existing scripts we have the `IN USERSPACE1 INDEX IN USERSPACE2 LONG IN USERSPACE3` clauses on every table create. If we use an `<sql>` tag on every create, we lose a lot of the advantages that Liquibase brings.

Comment: Yes, I know this is not an optimal solution. Just wanted to mention it as a possible work-around.

Comment: Another option could be to use [liquibase extension](https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/Overview) mechanism and add the missing functionality yourself - also not optimal because it might be too work intense - but it's an option to consider... You could check out the already existent [Oracle Extension](https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/Oracle+Extensions) or [Postgres Extension](https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/Postgres+Extensions) as an example...

Comment: Yes, I think I might have to do that. Or actually, just make a change to the core. It's something that DB2 can have, so ideally it should be in the DB2 support.

Comment: Woo! just saw your edit. I'm going to try that right away. Thanks.

Comment: Nearly, so nearly... it works as I'd like, up until I have a changeset with a remarks attribute. That generates a `COMMENT ON` clause as part of the `CREATE TABLE`, and the extra `INDEX IN USERSPACE2...` ends up after that, which is a syntax error.

Comment: Well, maybe you can leave out the remarks tag also and add it to the end using `modifySql`?

Comment: Thanks. Good thinking again. However, it turns out that (as I had first thought) The `COMMENT ON...` is a separate SQL statement. Liquibase is adding the content of `<modifySql>` after that statement, as well as after the `CREATE TABLE`. I think that's a bug in Liquibase, and will look into fixing it. Trouble is, it's ambiguous: the `<modifySql>` tag is inside the `<changeSet>`, not just inside the `<createTable>`.

Comment: I note that this issue has already been reported: [CORE-2190](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2190).

Comment: I have commented on the [CORE-2190](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2190) after looking at the sources. `modifySql` should be generic and not only be a modifier for `createTable`. There is a problem in liquibase though in the way the `remarks` is handeled. Did you already look into this? I started a [pull request](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/354) for it. Though it is untested and should be seen as a suggestion...

Comment: Adding a comment here for future reference, though I also commented on GitHub. Jens's fix is working for me (with a minor modification). Now, I just have to work out what I need to do to get the tablespace settings right on `CREATE INDEX` statements.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that is supported by the [Datical](http://www.datical.com/) extensions to Liquibase, but not in Liquibase itself.

Comment: Thanks. I'd forgotten about Datical. That costs, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, Datical does cost money. Disclaimer: I work for Datical. 

Our current customers are finding the additional features that we add worth the cost.

Comment: This makes me wonder, though: if we switched to using Datical, would we lose the advantage of using an open-source application? In the few weeks I've been working on getting our scripts into Liquibase I've made several changes to the code base to fix bugs and extend support. If we used Datical I would expect that to no longer be possible. Instead we'd have to raise bug reports and wait for fixes. Or would we still be able to make changes to the parts that are open source?

Comment: The open-source version of Liquibase is core to Datical, and we regularly bring in updates. The primary author of Liquibase (Nathan Voxland) is now working full-time for Datical, so we work very closely with him, and with the community. When I make changes to Liquibase, I submit them through the standard pull request process. Any of your changes would be handled similarly. You would potentially incur additional turnaround time, but you would gain the additional stability, testing, features, training, support, etc., that Datical provides.

Comment: Sorry to change my accepted answer. Yours is informative and would no doubt be a solution, but Jens's is working now.

Comment: No worries. I don't do S.O. for points, I do it to help people.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 6 years old, but I thought I'd post this as another possible solution. From their site they give the following as example

```
<changeSet id="2" author="liquibase">
   <createTable catalogName="department2"
          remarks="A String"
          schemaName="public"
          tableName="person"
          tablespace="${tablespace}">
        <column name="address" type="varchar(255)"/>
     </createTable>
   </changeSet>
```

Then define the tablespace name on the command line. If you had multiple you could provide multiple -D options

```
liquibase -Dtablespace='tablespaceQA' update
```