# Create column of type double precision[] with liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

How to create column of type double precision[] (array of doubles) with liquibase in postgresql database?

```
<changeSet id="add t_name table">
    <createTable tableName="t_name">
        ...
        <column name="doubleArray" type="???"/>
        ...
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

Google didn't help, please, if someone knows a solution, I will be very appreciative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the answer with help of my colleague.
It seems that liquibase don't know such types, so we need to modify sql query manually:

```
<createTable tableName="t_name">
    ...
    <column name="doubleArray" type="DOUBLE_ARRAY"/>
    ...
</createTable>

<modifySql dbms="postgresql">
    <replace replace="DOUBLE_ARRAY" with="double precision[][]"/>
</modifySql>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you rely on Postgresql, you can use the `float8` built-in alias:

```
<column name="doubleArray" type="float8[]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase 3.3.0 is able to generate precision for double type. e.g. "type=double precision[16][2]" generates double(16,2) in mysql.